# Как в js сделать смену фона при активности элемента

Tags: javascript, css, site

У меня есть слайдер с текстом. Там 6 элементов li. Мне нужно чтобы при активности первого элемента менялся фон блока всего, затем при активности второго менялся фон уже на другой и т.д[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код

Comment: Решение нужно на jQuery или на чистом JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приблизительно такое решение на `jQuery`. Можете изменять его соответственно вашей вёрстке.

UPD: упростил решение, вместо функции используется массив.

```js
var images = [
  'https://yandex.ru/images/today?size=1920x1080',
  'http://www.carscope.ru/piclib/1280/960/91699.jpeg',
  'https://ru9.anyfad.com/items/t1@a8c329ba-9f5c-40d1-92eb-b43b0d6edb37/Blyuda-iz-tykvy-recepty.jpg'
];

$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.content').css('background-image', 'url('+images[$('li.active').index()]+')');
});

$('.content li').click(function() {
  $('.content li').each(function() {$(this).removeClass('active');})
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.content').css('background-image', 'url('+images[$(this).index()]+')');
});
```

```css
.active a {
  color: red;
}

.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Первый элемент</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Второй элемент</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Третий элемент</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Неплохо бы еще добавить предварительную загрузку изображений, чтобы при смене слайдов они уже были полностью загружены

Comment: @Cheg в здешнем фрейме для примеров у меня загружается только картинка при первоначальной загрузке, а при смене они уже отображаются сразу.